# Me aparece falso en una consulta desde php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando editar lineas de una base de datos y cuando lo intento no puedo.

Aqui conforme llamo al proceso:

```
$economia = new Economia('', '','', $validador-> obtener_ingreso(), $validador-> obtener_gasto(), $validador -> obtener_nota());
        var_dump($economia);
        echo "</br>";
        $economia_editada = RepositorioEconomia :: editar_economia(Conexion :: obtener_conexion(), $economia, $id);
        var_dump($economia_editada);
```

Aqui $economia y $economia_editada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
object(Economia)#3 (6) { ["id_factura":"Economia":private]=> string(0) "" ["cliente":"Economia":private]=> string(0) "" ["fecha_dato":"Economia":private]=> string(0) "" ["ingreso":"Economia":private]=> string(1) "5" ["gasto":"Economia":private]=> string(2) "50" ["nota":"Economia":private]=> string(5) "wfweg" }

bool(false)

Aqui editar_economia Aqui deberia de rellenar un array con los datos y enviarlos:

    public static function editar_economia($conexion, $economia, $id){
            $economia_editada = [];
    
            if (isset($conexion)){
                try{
                    $sql = "UPDATE economia SET ingreso = :ingreso, gasto = :gasto, nota = :nota WHERE id_factura = :id";
    
                    $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $gasto = $economia->obtener_gasto();
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':gasto', $gasto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $ingreso = $economia->obtener_ingreso();
                    $sentencia->bindParam(':ingreso', $ingreso, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $nota = $economia->obtener_nota();
                    $sentencia -> bindParam(':nota', $nota, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    
                    $sentencia -> execute();
                    
                    $economia_editada = $sentencia -> fetch();
                }catch (PDOException $ex){
                    print 'ERROR'. $ex->getMessage();
                }
            }
            return $economia_editada;
        }
```

Comment: Hola. Pon el resultado del `var_dump` como texto, no como imagen, así  no se puede analizar el resultado completo. Pulsa en [edit] para ello.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu consulta es del tipo `UPDATE`, y PDO tiene un método específico para saber la cantidad de filas afectadas en consultas de tipo `DELETE`, `INSERT`, o `UPDATE`, ese método es [**`rowCount()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

> `PDOStatement::rowCount()` devuelve el número de filas afectadas por
> la última sentencia `DELETE`, `INSERT`, o `UPDATE` ejecutada por el
> correspondiente objeto `PDOStatement`.
>
> Si la última sentencia SQL ejecutada por el objeto `PDOStatement`
> asociado fue una sentencia `SELECT`, algunas bases de datos podrían
> devolver el número de filas devuelto por dicha sentencia. Sin embargo,
> este comportamiento no está garantizado para todas las bases de datos
> y no debería confiarse en él para aplicaciones portables.

Es importante que lo tengas presente, también el segundo párrafo, porque hay infinidad de ejemplos, de tutoriales y de respuestas incluso aquí que no saben diferenciar, usando `fetch` para consultas en las que no debe usarse (como es tu caso en esta pregunta) o bien usando `rowCount()` para consultas de tipo `SELECT` ignorando que esto puede fallar en algunos SGBD.

Ahora vamos a aplicar `rowCount()` para tu caso y mejoraremos otros aspectos que comentaré al final.

```
public static function editar_economia($conexion, $economia, $id){
    if ($conexion){
        try{
                $sql = "UPDATE economia SET ingreso = :ingreso, gasto = :gasto, nota = :nota WHERE id_factura = :id";

                $sentencia = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
                $sentencia->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $gasto = $economia->obtener_gasto();
                $sentencia->bindParam(':gasto', $gasto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $ingreso = $economia->obtener_ingreso();
                $sentencia->bindParam(':ingreso', $ingreso, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $nota = $economia->obtener_nota();
                $sentencia -> bindParam(':nota', $nota, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $sentencia -> execute();                
                return array("status"=>true, "msg"=>sprintf("Filas actualizadas: %s",$sentencia -> rowCount());
        }catch (PDOException $ex){
            # En producción evita mostrar mensajes de error internos
            return array ("status"=>false, "msg"=>sprintf("Error: %s",$ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
    return array ("status"=>false, "msg"=>"No hay conexión");
}
```

Si observas, he preferido un estilo basado en un array como respuesta. La convención es simple: habrá una clave `status` que será `false` cuando algún problema haya ocurrido, y será `true` cuando se hayan actualizado filas. En ambos casos habrá una clave `msg` con un mensaje informativo.

Para consumir la respuesta harías algo como esto:

```
$economia = new Economia('', '','', $validador-> obtener_ingreso(), $validador-> obtener_gasto(), $validador -> obtener_nota());
var_dump($economia);
echo "</br>";
$economia_editada = RepositorioEconomia :: editar_economia(Conexion :: obtener_conexion(), $economia, $id);
var_dump($economia_editada);

#-----------------------------
#Aquí aplicamos nuestra lógica
if($economia_editada['status']) {
    #Se actualizaron filas, actuar en consecuencia
} else {
    #Hubo error, activar protocolo de error
}
```

Comment: AL establecer eso me sale que se actualizan cero lineas pero sale la respuesta en true:

array(2) { ["status"]=> bool(true) ["msg"]=> string(21) "Filas actualizadas: 0" } 
Se actualizaron filas, actuar en consecuencia

                                                     No le meto la redireccion para comprobar los resultados que me dan, pero deberia de aztualizar las filas ya que la sentencia esta bien ejecutada.

Comment: Puede que estés intentando actualizar con los mismos valores que ya existen, @IsmaelMontoya, o que no haya filas a actualizar (porque el criterio del `WHERE` no se cumple) en cuyo caso la ejecución de la consulta será exitosa en sí misma, pero no actualizará nada, debes verificar eso en tus pruebas, intentando actualizar con datos distintos y verificando que hay filas que cumplan ese criterio.

Comment: Encontre el error y es que el id me lo devuelve como nulo, he intentado arreglarlo ya durante todo el dia, si no lo consigo al terminar lo expongo por aqui

Comment: Aqui el enlace de la pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/557316/dato-pasado-por-url-me-lo-inserta-como-nulo