# Dato pasado por url me lo inserta como nulo

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas estoy intentando editar una linea de una base de datos, cuando intento borrarla me aparece el ID como nulo, os explico el procedimiento.

editar-economia.php Aqui vemo que el dato pasado por url lo coge bien:

```
<h1>Editar linea Economia con Identificador <?php echo $id; ?></h1>
$linea = RepositorioEconomia::obtener_economia_id(Conexion::obtener_conexion(), $id);
```

Una parte de el codigo en el que añado el ID

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues de clickar el boton actualizar y tener quitada la redireccion me aparece este resultado con esta consulta:

```
$economia = new Economia($id, '','', $validador-> obtener_ingreso(), $validador-> obtener_gasto(), $validador -> obtener_nota());
        var_dump($economia);
```

Resultado:

object(Economia)#3 (6) { ["id_factura":"Economia":private]=> NULL ["cliente":"Economia":private]=> string(0) "" ["fecha_dato":"Economia":private]=> string(0) "" ["ingreso":"Economia":private]=> string(1) "5" ["gasto":"Economia":private]=> string(1) "0" ["nota":"Economia":private]=> string(7) "grerger" }

Como veis me aparece como nulo y nose por que, aqui dejo la pagina completa de redirecciones etc:

```
$id = $_GET["id"];


if (isset($_POST['editar_linea_economia'])){
    Conexion::abrir_conexion();
    $validador = new ValidadorEconomia($_POST["ingreso"], $_POST["gasto"], $_POST["nota"], Conexion :: obtener_conexion());
    
    if ($validador -> economia_valida()){
        $economia = new Economia($id, '','', $validador-> obtener_ingreso(), $validador-> obtener_gasto(), $validador -> obtener_nota());
        var_dump($economia);
        echo "</br>";
        $economia_editada = RepositorioEconomia :: editar_economia(Conexion :: obtener_conexion(), $economia, $id);
        var_dump($economia_editada);
        
        if($economia_editada['status']) {
            echo "Se actualizaron filas, actuar en consecuencia";
        } else {
            echo "Hubo error, activar protocolo de error";
        }

        if (isset($economia_editada)){
            if (headers_sent()) {
                // las cabeceras ya se han enviado, no intentar añadir una nueva
                echo "No se ha insertado ninguna linea";
            }
            else {
                // es posible añadir nuevas cabeceras HTTP
              //Redireccion::redirigir("http://localhost:8080/prueba/clientes/clientes.php");

            }
            
            
        }
        
        }else{
            echo "el validador ha fallado";
        }

}

                                    
                                
                                    


?>

            <p>
            <h1>Editar linea Economia con Identificador <?php echo $id; ?></h1>
            </p>
        </div>
       
                        <?php

                        
                    Conexion::abrir_conexion();
                    $linea = RepositorioEconomia::obtener_economia_id(Conexion::obtener_conexion(), $id);
                    EscritorioEconomia::editar_entradas($linea);
                    Conexion::cerrar_conexion();
```

Boton actualizar:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn-basura" name="editar_linea_economia">Actualizar</button>
```

Comment: veo un detalle en tu codigo, cuando haces esto ```$id = $_GET["id"];``` estas tratando de obtener mediante GET el id que aparece en el link, pero luego veo que haces un llamado al metodo POST y en tu codigo no veo como mandas ese formulario, posiblemente al enviar el formulario estas perdiendo el id que tratas de recuperar con get, porque no colocas ese id en un campo oculto y lo pasas como post? asi evitas perder información

Comment: Si el problema es el valor del ID explícanos de dónde surge (un formulario supongo) y muéstranos ese formulario, si es vía Ajax o Fetch, muéstranos el código que recoge y manda los datos. Las capturas de pantalla no sirven de nada en este caso, necesitamos ver **código**. También, como te ha señalado @ernestojimenez, debes aclararte con el método que usas para transportar los datos, si es GET usa la superglobal `$_GET` y si es POST usa la superglobal `$_POST`. Sea como sea, es bueno que aprendas a depurar tu código, pon un `var_dump($_GET);` o un `var_dump($_POST);` y dinos qué muestra.

Comment: Solucionado, ahora expongo la respuesta, era lo que me habiais explicado de recibir valores con GET o POST, no se me habia ocurrido pasar por pantalla GET o POST eso me ayudo mucho y como deciais en $_GET no me cogia nada al pulsar el boton.

Comment: A otra parte en este editor de linea lo estoy trabajando con un enlace a otra apgina y desde esa pagina a tengo un input permanente para hacerlo mas sencillo, un compañero me sugirio hacerlo con javascript para convertir en la pagina principal un span en input y me seria mas sencillo, me gustaria saber vuestra opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al mirar que con $_GET me devolvía un array vacío, y leer las aclaraciones de los compañeros he buscado poner el id con POST desde el GET.

En el formulario el campo lo establezco como un input:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>">
                        <tr>
                            <form role="form" method="post" action="editar_economia_accion.php">
                            <td>
                            
                                <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="number" min="<?php echo $l_economia['id_factura'] ?>" max="<?php echo $l_economia['id_factura'] ?>" class="form-control" name="id_factura" value="<?php echo $l_economia['id_factura'] ?>" placeholder="ID FACTURA">
                                </div>
                            
                            </td>
```

editar_economia_accion.php Aqui he añadido el dato que quiero mandar:

```
echo $_POST["id_factura"];
```

En la pagina principal cuando envio los datos ya he establecido el POST:

```
$economia_editada = RepositorioEconomia :: editar_economia(Conexion :: obtener_conexion(), $economia, $_POST["id_factura"]);
```

He cambiado $id por $_POST["id_factura"]

Comment: Deberías tener cuidado con el uso de `PHP_SELF` en el `action` de tu formulario, revisa [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/239658/29967) para más detalles. Lo mejor para comunicar entre cliente y servidor es usar Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. Ambas herramientas te permiten llevar y traer información de ambos lados de una forma transparente, segura y sin necesidad de recargar la página cada vez que quieras mandar algo y/o actualizar la página cuando hayas recibido la respuesta. Cuando puedas te aconsejo que te adentres en el mundo de Ajax o de Fetch, ambos son sencillos.